# Can I fork a Codeplex repo to GitHub?

Tags: github, fork, codeplex

Simple question, is it possible to fork a Codeplex repo on my GitHub?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [GitHub Importer](https://import.github.com/new) and read its [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-other-version-control-systems-to-github/).

Comment: From GitHub Importer: "Imports from Codeplex's SVN bridge are not supported, because Codeplex does not support svnrdump. Please try importing from Codeplex+TFS, or maybe use svn2git."

From CodePlex: "Only project members can connect to the project using TFS. Non-members may use Subversion to access the repository."

I guess I'll have to clone locally and add github as a second remote, as described [here](http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2012/09/26/CloneCodePlexRepositoryToGitHub/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need first to clone the Codeplex repo using Git, as shown in "[Using Git with CodePlex](https://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Git%20with%20CodePlex)"

Then you can change the rmeote "origin", and point it the a new and empty GitHub repo that you would have created.

```
cd /path/to/local/clone
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/username/newrepo
git push --mirror
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is SVN repository, you can't use github importer, bitbucket importer, `git svn`, `svnrdump` and even `git2svn` (it's just incompatible and causes errors because that's not real svn but TFS) - so you can only checkout and push to github the last version of repository. Losing all history is really sad.
2. If you want to fork a git repository from codeplex, you can do it like with any other git repository - just like [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) described in his answer - add both origins, pull from codeplex and push to github.